# Approximation of the cavity reflection coefficient (Pound–Drever–Hall technique)

Tags: optics, laser, laser-cavity

In context of the Pound-Drever-Hall lock (p. 83 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1286663) to be precise), I stumbled over the approximation of the reflexion coefficient for a symmetric cavity with amplitude reflexion coefficent $0<r<1$ and frequency $x$ (in units of the free spectral range):

\begin{equation}
F(x):=\frac{r\left(e^{i2\pi x}-1\right)}{1-r^2e^{i2\pi x}}.
\end{equation}

For the case of sidebands at frequencies $\omega\pm\Omega$, where $\Omega\ll 1$ (again, in units of the free spectral range), the following approximations were made (this term appears in the photodiode signal of the beam reflected from the cavity):

\begin{align}
F(x)F^*(x+\Omega)-F^*(x)F(x-\Omega) & \approx 2\, \mathrm{Re}\left(F(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}F^*(x)\right)\Omega\\
& \approx \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}|F(x)|^2\right)\Omega.
\end{align}

While the first step is a simple Taylor approximation about $\Omega = 0$, the second step doesn't become clear to me. Is this a general property of a complex function? Is this an approximation for the near resonance regime (i.e. $x$ is approximately integer)?